# jQuery AJAX Button Click - Remove Table Row after AJAX Call is Successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm displaying an HTML table and would like to include a button in the last column that, when clicked, performs an AJAX call which will result in the removal of the table row from the table. I'm new to jQuery and AJAX and working things out as I go - I've managed to setup some AJAX calls that run when a field is edited, but now I'm struggling to attach one to a button in a table row.

Here's how the table looks:

```
<tr class="" id="tableRow1"><td><a href="projectDetails.php?action=viewProject&id=DA0993D3-F559-4ADB-BD3A-33EA6A812FE9">Store 1</a></td><td>lorem ipsum</td><td>John Smith</td><td>20/11/2014 12:53:52 AM</td><td><button type="button" id="closeNote" class="btn btn-primary">Acknowledge</button></td></tr>
 <tr class="" id="tableRow2"><td><a href="projectDetails.php?action=viewProject&id=BA10F0A9-1778-4606-90D3-318E75070B2C">Store 2</a></td><td>lorem ipsum</td><td>Sally Jones</td><td>20/11/2014 12:53:52 AM</td><td><button type="button" id="closeNote" class="btn btn-primary">Acknowledge</button></td></tr>
 <tr class="" id="tableRow3"><td><a href="projectDetails.php?action=viewProject&id=058EC9C0-E913-44A8-8BD6-8AB9B8EA3CDF">Store 3</a></td><td>lorem ipsum </td><td>Bill Howden</td><td>12/11/2014 01:43:03 PM</td><td><button type="button" id="closeNote" class="btn btn-primary">Acknowledge</button></td></tr>
```

I know that the ID for the button is not unique - at the moment the script only fires when the button in the first row is clicked. I'm not sure how to assign a unique ID for each button which the script can see.

Here's my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#closeNote").click(function(){
        $.post('editNote.php', { type: 'hideNote', id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.error) {
                $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger").html(data.text);
                $("#ajaxAlert").show();
                return; // stop executing this function any further
            } else { 
                $("#ajaxAlert").hide();
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }

        }).fail(function (xhr) {
            // no data available in this context
            $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
            //display AJAX error details
            $("#ajaxAlert").html(xhr.responseText);
            $("#ajaxAlert").show();
        });
     }); 
});
</script>
```

I just need some help in bring this altogether so that when the button is clicked on any row it calls the script which in turn, if the PHP script it then calls is successful, it then removes the row where the button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than applying the button to an ID give each link a class:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary close-note"
```

Then amend your JS as follows:

```
$("button.close-note").click(function(){
```

Inside your callback functions the keyword `this` no longer refers to the element, but instead refers to the `XHR` object.

To solve this assign $(this) to a variable outside of the `$.post`

```
var $self = $(this);
$.post( ... ... function(response){
    // code and stuff
    $self.closest('tr').hide();
});
```

You also need to ensure that the browser doesn't then follow the link; amend the `click` line again:

```
.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I need the script to run when the user clicks the button in the last column of the table, not when they click the link that is in the first column of the table.

Comment: OK; all that's needed is to replace `a` with `button` in my answer, which I've now done. This is another reason why using an explicit element where possible in your selectors is good, it helps other people (including future you!) read the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far - the button already has a class which I need to keep (from the Bootstrap framework) of "btn btn-primary". If I change the script to "$("button.btn btn-primary").click(function(){" nothing happens when I click the button. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not how selectors work. Space will indicate that you're looking for a descendant. You could do `$("button.btn.btn-primary")` or `$(".btn")` or `$(".btn-primary")` or `$(".btn.btn-primary")` or `$("button.btn")` or `$("button.btn-primary")` or '$(".btn-primary.btn")` or pretty much any combination that doesn't include spaces :)

Comment: You should also add this class; the btn and btn-primary classes are likely to be used elsewhere in your code eventually and you don't want this click event binding to every button. I've amended the code in the answer to show you can keep your current classes. The user above is right that to add multiple classes to a selector you chain them using `.` characters, but you're best off using a specific class for this selector.